# fastcgi_finish_request() does not always work

Tags: php, nginx

I need to delay some hard operations, so i'm using fastcgi_finish_request()

```
echo "Test";
fastcgi_finish_request();
sleep(10);
```

Generally, it works, but if i have a lot of queries (several per second), i noticed that after 5-6 queries they begin to take too long time (from 4 to 6 seconds) to execute. 
What is the reason for that?

Comment: I guess, you have a pool of PHP workers and they all are busy  with `sleep`ing.

Comment: how could i check that?